# Create linked values In a CoreData Model (relationships between entities) in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, uipickerview, relationships

I have a question :

I would like to add values in a core data model with relationships between entities and display those values in a View with pickersView.

I have created an example to try to understand how to implement relationships between entities but now i am in stand-by ...  I do not know how to use mutableSetValueForKey, valueforkey, setvalue(_:forkey) in my model. in my example, devices or cards are linked to an upper item.

my coreData model : 3 entities : User, Device and Card
User - Device (nn) : n devices to n users
Device - card (1n) : 1 device can have several cards but one card is only for one dedicated device

See image of the model:

[CoreData Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7xR8.png)

To populate, i have a view with several fields, Pickers, buttons :

Usertexfield + add button to add new user

- Picker of users (display / sélect users) + devicetextfield + add button to add new device to a user
- Picker of device (display /sélect device) + cardtextfield + add button to add new card to a Device
- Picker of cards (display / sélect cards)
- delete device button to remove a device
- delete card button to remove a card

I would like also to be able to modify a device or card when selected (not Made)

---

***Question*** : 
How to create/modify/delete a Device associated to a user (how to implement the relationship between those 2 entities in the fetchrequest ?

here is my code (not finish at all ...) : see addDeviceButton function (and addCardButton as well if possible)

```
    //  createRelationshipsViewController.swift
    //  testcoredatarelationships
    //
    //  Created by jIOP on 23/03/2016.
    //  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class createRelationshipsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

        // User
        @IBOutlet weak var pickerUser: UIPickerView!
        @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var boutonAddUser: UIButton!


        // Device
        @IBOutlet weak var pickerDevice : UIPickerView!
        @IBOutlet weak var deviceNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var boutonAddDevice: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var deleteActivite: UIButton!

        //Card
        @IBOutlet weak var pickerCard : UIPickerView!
        @IBOutlet weak var carteNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var boutonAddcard: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var deleteCard: UIButton!

        //Actions

        var tabpickerUser=[]
        var tabpickerDevice=[]
        var tabpickerCard=[]


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


                    // init PickerView User only -others can't be at this time

            let MOC = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
            var requestError: NSError?

            /* And exécute the fetch request on the context */
            usersInCD = (try! MOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [User]
            //   usersInCD is a list of Users  
            // tbd --> if nil picker is empty else init tabpickerUser with usersInCD.Name.

              }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        @IBAction func addUserBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

            let MOCUser = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
            let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User",inManagedObjectContext: MOCUser) as! User

            newUser.userId = NSUUID().UUIDString
            newUser.userName = userNameTextField.text // new user textfield

            var savingError: NSError?
            do {
                try MOCUser.save()
                print("New User created")

            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                savingError = error1
                if let error = savingError
                {
                    print("Failed to populate the database User. Error = \(error)")

                }
        // Update UserPicker --> Tbd

        }

        @IBAction func addDeviceBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

            let MOCDevice = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

            // How to get userId from PickerView 
            // How to create a new device attached to this userId (predicate, mutableSetValueForKey, other ...)

            let newDevice = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Device",inManagedObjectContext: MOCDevice) as! Device

            newDevice.deviceId = NSUUID().UUIDString
            newDevice.deviceName = deviceNameTextField.text

            var savingError: NSError?
            do {
                try MOCDevice.save()
                print("New device created")

            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                savingError = error1
                if let error = savingError
                {
                    print("Failed to populate the database Device. Error = \(error)")

                }
        }


        @IBAction func addCardBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        // same PB but with n--1 relationships between Device and Cards 
        // A card is associated to 1 device only / one device car have several cards
        // usage of mutableSetValueForKey ?

        }


        @IBAction func deleteDeviceBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
            // How to delete device (device) --> device will delete the card ?


        }


        @IBAction func deleteCardBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
                    // How to delete card, link to a device
        }

/////////////////////////// Picker managment        

        func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView:UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
                }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,numberOfRowsInComponent component:Int) -> Int {

            switch pickerView.tag {
            case 1:
                return tabpickerUser.count
            case 2:
                return tabpickerDevice.count
            case 3:
                return tabpickerCard.count
            default:
                print("Something else")
            }

        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

            switch pickerView.tag {
                case 1:
                    return tabpickerUser[row] as! String
                case 2:
                    return tabpickerDevice[row]as! String
                case 3:
                    return tabpickerCard[row]as! String
                default:
                    print("Something else")
                }

        }



  // Here add pickerView functions to update pickers views when user, device, card is added or remove.
// not done ...           
        /*     Init pickerView Device and pickerView Card (how to do it ?)
               Init pickerView Device when user is selected in UserpickerView

                let MOC = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

                 // predicate to match UserId in Entity Device ?? how to do it using the relationships ????
                 //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId == %@", tabpickerUser[row].userId!)   ???????
                 fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                  var requestError: NSError?
                  /* And execute the fetch request on the context */
                  Devices = (try! MOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [Device]

        */


        /*       Init pickerViewCard when Device is selected in DevicepickerView

                let MOC = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Card")
                var requestError: NSError?

                // And execute the fetch request on the context
                Cards = (try! MOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [Card]
        */
        }
```